# window.onload is not working in react sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I am encountering an issue where the `window.onload` event does not consistently trigger in React when I refresh the page, resulting in API calls not being made.

My example code:

```
function layout(WrappedComponent) {
  return function Layout(props) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const UserInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await me();
        const authUser = response.data.user;

        dispatch(updateOnboardingSteps(authUser.onboarding_steps_state));

      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong at user data fetching.");
      }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
      UserInfo();
    };

    return (
      <>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} UserInfo={UserInfo}/>
      </>
    );
  };
}
```

In this code, I created a layout by using a higher-order(HOC) function. It fetches user data and updates the Redux store state.

**Reminder:** I'm using it as layout and a lot of pages using it so if I use the `useEffect` hook then on visiting every page the hook will be called.

Comment: Why are you stomping the global `window.onload` handler instead of adding an event listener? Better yet, why aren't you just using a mounting `useEffect` hook to make the API requests, it's what it is for?

Comment: Most likely you call your `Layout` function after `window.onload` was already fired

Comment: @DrewReese the problem is that if he use the `useEffect` hook for API call whenever the route change that API will be called because it is a layout created by HOC design pattern. Basically he needs a solution to run API one time only whenever user refresh the page or comes to the page by entering the `URL`.

Comment: You probably don't want to mix UI layout routes with data fetching. If you want to only fetch the data once when the app loads/mounts then you'll want to move the fetching logic out of the routes. Lift the state and effect higher in the ReactTree to a component that remains mounted for the duration of the app lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function given to useEffect to run just on the first load, you can give it an empty array as a second argument of useEffect, after the callback function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    UserInfo();
}, []);
```